# access to a image in the view/admin/sub_folder

Tags: codeigniter

I have a subfolder in "views/admin/my_folder".

Inside of this, is a image "test.jpg".

If I use the link "views/admin/my_folder/test.jpg" to display it I receive a error 403 - access denied.

The link will be generated from a part of the controller in this way

```
APP_BASE_URL.'application/views/admin/my_folder/test.jpg
```

So how I can display this image (and use it inside the other php-files from the "my_folder" and/or in the controller and model) - or in which file(s) I have to do something else so that I can have access to this image?

Comment: try to keep your assets like images,css and js file out of application folder create a assets folder keep them there, to access images user img(img_path) html helper method or base_url(img_path).

Comment: move the folder is not the solution for my problem, i think there must be a way to get access!?

Comment: remove .htaccess file from your application folder and check, .htaccess in application for your application protection script direct call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long term for looking for a better way, i have to accept that i shoul move the folder outside the application - this is much more easier and more secure as do a lot of change at the router and other settings...